# Firefox Ubiquity - remove old verbs

Tags: firefox

Since upgrading to ubiquity 0.5, I get the message

```
Ubiquity notification
some verbs were not loaded as they are not compatible with parser 2
```

Every time I start firefox.

Looking in my command list, the only command listed as using the "old api" is the example command, which points at ubiquity://command-editor-code ... how can I remove or update this command so it doesn't popup that message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it!

sneaky git was hidden away in C:\Documents and Settings\[user]\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[random].default\extensions\ubiquity@labs.mozilla.com\chrome\content\command-template.js

looks like the template wasnt updated for 0.5 and consequently was invalid for parser 2.0.

I just went in and cleared out the content of the file except for the comment at the top :)

Answer (score 3):

*Note: I don't have the command you are referencing and since you cannot unsub from builtin commands this might not be helpful.*

I had the "flip" command using the old API, and therefore was getting the same annoying pop-up as you.  I have gotten rid of it by purging the "flip" command.

1. Unsubscribe

   [image: Unsubscribe From Feed]
2. Purge the Command (from the list of unsubscribed feeds at the bottom of the about:ubiquity page)

   [image: Purge Command]

Comment: thanks for replying :) 

unfortunately as you've said, as it's a built in command I only have the option to [view auto-updated source]

Comment: also, I've tried uninstalling completely, and reinstalling 0.5, but the command is still there... perhaps not all the files are removed when the addon is removed?

Comment: Ok. I was able to remove the "builtin commands" from my "chrome://ubiquity/content/cmdlist.xhtml" list by removing the "builtincmds.js" file from <path to user apps data>/Firefox/Profiles/<random id>.default/extensions/ubiquity@labs.mozilla.com/builtin-feeds/ The header still shows up in the list, but no commands. If you can find the file containing the file you should be able to remove it this way. Good luck.

Comment: hehe unfortunately, deleting the file you suggest removes all the commands like "help" "list" etc! so that's no good, also the command I am having trouble with is under its own header which reads "ubiquity://command-editor-code"

Comment: also looks like it's the example template command that's shown in chrome://ubiquity/content/editor.xhtml when you click "import command template"... wonder where that's stored?